# Databricks table usage read/writes in a database

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

Was trying to google how to obtain some read/write usage statistics for tables in a database with spark sql, no success however.

It can be as simple as:

table1 | 3 times this month
table2 | 4 times this month

Or any other more specific statistics will do.
I'm not an owner of the TAC cluster, so don't have a detailed access to driver logs.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configure diagnostic log delivery

1. Log in to the Azure portal as an Owner or Contributor for the Azure Databricks workspace and click your Azure Databricks Service resource.
2. In the Monitoring section of the sidebar, click the Diagnostic settings tab.
3. Click Turn on diagnostics.
   On the Diagnostic settings page, provide the following configuration:
4. Name
5. Enter a name for the logs to create.
6. Archive to a storage account

[image]

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/databricks-monitoring/application-logs